# Hardware problem encountered while running a Three.js demo

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, three.js

I tried to view a three.js demo (/skinning/morph) from it's official site on my desktop.(specs at the end). It got loaded, then was trying various states and emotes. Then while I set the state as 'dead' and emote to 'no' , suddenly, the entire screen got stuck and the monitor screen was flickering and stretching continuously. I let it be for 10-15 minutes, still nothing happened. So I rebooted my desktop. Now it is not booting up. On my laptop and phone the same demo worked properly. On my desktop, I had worked with canvas before, but didn't have any problems running. Is it because of that particular three.js demo consuming my PC hardware resources too much ? Or maybe the monitor was faulty ? Shouldn't just the Browser screen get hanged if the PC is not able to render the graphics ?

Specs:
CPU : intel i5 2300 32bit@3.1Ghz
GPU : integrated GPU (Intel HD graphics)
RAM : 4GB